# HexString to Decimal Convert Error : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: startIndex

Tags: c#, serial-port, hex, decimal

I try to make a receiver software which convert hexadecimal value from serial to decimal value. This is my code :

```
       // Obtain the number of bytes waiting in the port's buffer 
       int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;

        // Create a byte array buffer to hold the incoming data
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];

        // Read the data from the port and store it in our buffer
        comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

        string hexValues = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer);
        string[] hexValuesSplit = hexValues.Split(' ');
        foreach (String hex in hexValuesSplit)
        {
            // Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer. 
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
            Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, value+" ppm \n");
        }
```

But when I try to send data from serial it always say that "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: startIndex". So What shoul I do?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: I suspect it's in `ByteArrayToHexString`, which you haven't provided :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :** while using String.Split() function if the string is EMPTY then it returns EMPTY string,

I suspect this statement causes the Exception:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
```

if the `hex` value is Empty then it causes the `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative Exception.`

**Solution 1:** You need to Remove the empty entries by providing `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as second argument to the `Split()` function.

Try This:

```
string[] hexValuesSplit = hexValues.Split(new []{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**OR**

**Solution 2 :** You can simply check the `hex` variable for `Null` or `Empty` using `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` method.

```
string[] hexValuesSplit = hexValues.Split(' ');
foreach (String hex in hexValuesSplit)
{
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hex))
 {
   // Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer. 
   int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
   Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, value+" ppm \n");
 }
}
```

Comment: @JonSkeet: if the `hex` value is EMPTY it throws the `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative` Exception.

Comment: You're right, it does - which is a very poor implementation, given that there *is* no `startIndex` parameter here.

Comment: @Sudhakar : Thank you very much! both solution are work good!